# How to set an existing key in the registry editor using C sharp

Tags: c#, registry, regedit

I have the following problem,

I want to open the LongPathsEnabled key to change its value using c# Registry (using Microsoft.Win32). This is the usual key that exists on windows 10.

so far reading it is no problem:

```
int valueoflongPaths = (int)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem", "LongPathsEnabled", null);
```

but I get a problem when setting it. I want to set it to 1:

```
RegistryKey key=Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled", true);                   
key.SetValue("Value", (int)1);
key.Close();
```

i get the following error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

so far when I google the problem I only find examples of creating keys that don't exist and not of existing usual keys.
Am I missing something here?

I use .NET 4.6 and windows 10

Thanks

Comment: `SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem` is a subkey. `LongPathsEnabled` is a value. Thus when you try and open the 'subkey' `SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled` it returns null. You're calling `Registry.GetValue` to get the value, so you call [`Registry.SetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry.setvalue) to set the value.

Comment: thanks. but then i get a requested registry access is not allowed, although when i open it i put the option to true

Comment: Ah, well that's a different question..

Comment: is it possible to force the access ?

Comment: Are you running the code with administrative rights?

Comment: no. is there a way to force it somehow just for this operation?

Comment: As I understand it, elevating to admin rights has to be [for the whole app, not just for one operation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/197/administration-elevation).

Comment: good, thank you very much for your help. I was wondering if there was a way to deactivate it just for this operation. I was thrown off by reading the value which seems ok when one does not have administrator rights. but apparently setting the value is another operation.

Comment: Applications need to be able to read the values, but admin rights are required to change them.